# Can shapeless recipes have multiple outputs in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: json, minecraft

I am relatively new to making addons and stuff, and this is my first recipe. I am trying to add a shapeless recipe for cheese that includes a brown mushroom and a milk bucket. I want it to return the bucket, but I get an error message: `\[Recipes\]\[error\]-recipes/cheese_from_brown_mushroom.json | pizza:cheese | unsupported multiple output types for result list in shapeless`

Is there a way I can fix this?

Here is my code:

```
{
  "format_version": "1.12",
  "minecraft:recipe_shaped": {
    "description": {
      "identifier": "pizza:cheese_from_brown_mushroom"
    },

 
    "tags": [ "crafting_table" ],
    "ingredients": [
      {
        "item": "minecraft:milk_bucket"
      },
      {
        "item": "minecraft:brown_mushroom"
      }
    ],
    "result": [
      { "item": "pizza:cheese" },
      { "item": "minecraft:bucket" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No There can only be one output. You do not need to set the bucket as a result. like when you craft a cake in the game the bucket will be left in the crafting table

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about shapeless recipes, but shaped recipes can have more than one output.  Here's the vanilla recipe for a cake in Bedrock.  Note that the result is cake and three empty buckets.

Looking at your code, I noticed that you have "minecraft:recipe_shaped" on your 2nd line, but the rest of your code is for a shapeless recipe.  Here's a resource that can help with making addons:  https://bedrock.dev/docs/1.12.0.0/1.12.0.2/Addons.

And since shaped recipes can have multiple outputs (see the Bedrock vanilla recipe for cake below), you might try using a shaped recipe.

Bedrock vanilla cake recipe:

```
{
 "format_version": "1.20.10",
 "minecraft:recipe_shaped": {
   "description": {
     "identifier": "minecraft:cake"
   },
   "tags": [ "crafting_table" ],
   "pattern": [
    "AAA",
    "BEB",
    "CCC"
   ],
   "key": {
    "A": {
      "item": "minecraft:bucket",
      "data": 1
    },
    "B": {
      "item": "minecraft:sugar"
    },
    "C": {
      "item": "minecraft:wheat"
    },
    "E": {
      "item": "minecraft:egg"
    }
   },
   "unlock": [
    {
      "item": "minecraft:egg"
    }
   ],
   "result": [
    { "item": "minecraft:cake" },
    { "item": "minecraft:bucket", "count": 3, "data": 0 }
   ]
 }
}
```